# pipenv: only works in a installed folder?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv

Pipenv seems to work only in the directory where the Pipfile lives. Maybe I'm trying to use it in a way it is not designed for.

For example, I installed a tool called "leo" (an editor) and no surprise that I will go to many folders and start `pipenv run Leo` and it will start to install another virtual environment. What's the workaround?

Comment: Just use `pipenv shell` in the project directory with the pipfile, then you can move about freely.

Comment: `virtualenv` isn't so unwieldy that you need a second tool to wrap it.

Comment: @BallpointBen when the question is about using a tool, i don't think 'don't use that tool' is a helpful response.

Comment: I am suggesting using a different tool

Comment: thanks... pipenv shell kind of does the job... only a small pain... I need to go to the folder to do "pipenv shell", right?

Comment: @JeremyChen Yes, I don't know of any way to specify the path to the virtualenv other than running in that directory.

Comment: @wowserx thanks. I guess I will use my old tool pyenv for this kind of workflow.

Comment: @JeremyChen Out of curiosity, how were you hoping to specify which virtualenv to activate?

Comment: I forgot that part. Using pyenv, I can use "pyenv activate leo" so I was hoping to do the same like "pipenv activate leo" and "pipenv run leo". Probably a future feature.

Comment: @JeremyChen You can use `pipenv —venv` in your pipfile directory to get the location of the virtualenv, and then activate it in the same way as any other.

Comment: @wowserx the question is about executing `pipenv run [...]` from another dir, not executing `pipenv shell`. @XiUpsilon already proposed your solution in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55155107/5684214).

Answer (score 8):

You can run [`pew`](https://pypi.org/project/pew) from any directory:

```sh
# install pew using pip (not pipenv)
$ pip install pew
   ...

# get venv name
$ (cd <folder with Pipfile> && pipenv --venv)
<some path>/python-1234ABCD

# activate venv
$ pew workon python-1234ABCD

# run pipenv as usual
$ pipenv run leo
```

As far as I understand it, you can only execute commands like running a text editor with pipenv if you are currently already running a virtual environment with pipenv. If not, it will make a new virtual env in the current directory and then run the command in it.

The result of `pipenv --help` says, for the run command:

> run        Spawns a command installed into the virtualenv.

Answer (score 4):

At the directory where Pipfile resides, do

```sh
pipenv --venv
```

This will show the path where the virtual env is located. Copy that path, such as `/Users/yourname/.local/share/virtualenvs/yourproject-8XhejQjj`, and at any other folder you can activate the venv with `source`, e.g.:

```sh
source /Users/yourname/.local/share/virtualenvs/yourproject-8XhejQjj/bin/activate
```

This is covered by [Ken Reitz's 2018 PyData talk](https://youtu.be/GBQAKldqgZs?t=1475).

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to your question but I also ran into the problem of running a console app from another directory. I'm not sure if this is the best/"most portable" solution but if you're happy with having a bash script as an intermediate:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

CURRENT="$(dirname "$0")"
ROOT_DIR="$CURRENT/.."

(cd $ROOT_DIR && pipenv run python3 app/console.py "$@")
```

and here's what my projects directory structure looks like:

```
.
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── console.py
└── bin
    └── console
```

and now you're able to run `/absolute/path/to/bin/console` from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to google this but I found the best solution.

To easily activate a virtual environment anywhere with pipenv, you can use **pew**.

Once you **pip install pew**, you can easily do "pew workon myvenv".

Pew uses pipenv under the hood and it works on Windows too.

Comment: Technically it’s the other way around—Pipenv uses Pew under the hood, so its virtualenvs are compatible with Pew :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Pipenv only works in the directory that the Pipfile is in (or its subdirectories).

If you want a way to install Python programs into their own virtual environment, while still being able to use them anywhere, you can use [pipsi](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/pipsi) – once it's installed, you can just do `pipsi install <package>` to install a Python package into its own virtualenv.

(If you're feeling brave, [my fork of pipsi](https://github.com/anowlcalledjosh/pipsi/tree/develop) has a few fixes and improvements that haven't found their way into the main repository yet. You can install it by passing `--src git+https://github.com/anowlcalledjosh/pipsi@develop#egg=pipsi` to the `get-pipsi.py` script.)